# Paypal Plan MULTIPLE_FREE_TRIAL_BILLING_CYCLE_NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

In the [Paypal documentation][1], it mentions under `tenure_type`:

> The tenure type of the billing cycle. In case of a plan having trial cycle, only 2 trial cycles are allowed per plan.

If we want to do a free trial for 366 days, we'd set up a plan like this:

```
"billing_cycles": [
{
  "frequency": {
    "interval_unit": "DAY",
    "interval_count": 1
  },
  "sequence": 1,
  "tenure_type": "TRIAL",
  "total_cycles": 1
},
{
  "frequency": {
    "interval_unit": "YEAR",
    "interval_count": 1
  },
  "sequence": 2,
  "tenure_type": "TRIAL",
  "total_cycles": 1
},
{
  "frequency": {
    "interval_unit": "YEAR",
    "interval_count": 1
  },
  "tenure_type": "REGULAR",
  "total_cycles": 0,
  "sequence": 3,
}
]
```

But this returns the error:

> {"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.","debug_id":"37d4b8ed61f65","details":[{"field":"/billing_cycles","location":"body","issue":"MULTIPLE_FREE_TRIAL_BILLING_CYCLE_NOT_SUPPORTED","description":"Only one free trial billing cycle is allowed."}],"links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]}

What am I misunderstanding here?  The objective here is to have a trial period which is not whole years but over 1 year in length, eg 400 days.  Paypal doesn't allow and `interval_unit` of `DAY` to be greater than 365.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be up to 2 trial periods to a plan. Only one of the trial periods can be for $0 per cycle. The second trial period, if one exists, must be for > $0 per cycle.

Comment: Thanks for this, in this case then for a 400 day trial it would make most sense to do a 200 day trial with a cycle count  of 2?

Comment: 100 for 4 installments (cycles) might be easier to understand if the payer looks at the cart in the upper right of the checkout, but either will work